# Regex - capture each argument in seperate capture group: [cmd arg1 arg2 arg3...]

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to create a regex for detecting some commands in a text file.
These commands have the format: `[cmd arg1 arg2 arg3...]` and can be positioned anywhere in the file. Multiple commands may be on the same line. They are always in `[]` brackets and the first word should consist of only alphabetic characters, which can be followed by a number. Arguments are separated with spaces and can contain any character except `],[`. A command may have no arguments. The regex should consist of multiple capture groups so that the command (the first word in "[]") and the arguments are captured in a separate capture group (each argument in its own group).

Given the input:

```
some text... [cmd1 arg1 arg2 arg3] some other text! [cmd2 #] [cmd3]
[error[ error] error] .error]
[]
[.error] [1]
end
```

the commands:

```
{cmd1, arg1, arg2, arg3}
{cmd2, #}
{cmd3}
```

should be captured. I am currently using [`\[([A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)\s?([^\[\]]*)\]`](https://regexr.com/61q8p) for detecting these commands. This works quite well however, the arguments are grouped into one capture group. If it matters I am trying to create a little preprocessor that can include a file into another for GLSL in C++. Currently, I am using two regexes: one for detecting commands and a second one for separating the arguments but I wondered if there is a solution that uses only one regex.

Comment: In `[a [b c d] e]` is `b c d` valid, or not?

Comment: @jhnc "b c d" is valid

Comment: "... but I wondered if there is a solution that uses only one regex." No, this is not possible in RegEx alone. The approach you have is a suitable workaround.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 Thank you very much! You may write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but I wondered if there is a solution that uses only one regex.

No, this is not possible in RegEx alone. The approach you have is a suitable workaround.